# Access an angular page from a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, url, get

I would like to access an angular page from an html form. But when I submit the form via method get and with parameter I get some problem with the url.

Here is a simple form to reproduce the problem :

```
<form action="http://ncel28182/pl/Angular/#/FFCO">
       <input type="text" name="test">
       <button>toto</button>
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button, it open a page where the url is

```
http://ncel28182/pl/Angular/?test=#/FFCO
```

It seems that the parameters are placed before the #.

Is there a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use $location to change location, and a service to share data, as in the following :

HTML :

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <button>toto</button>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
function submit($scope, $location, MyService) {
  MyService.data = $scope.myForm.test;
  $location.url("/pl/Angular/#/FFCO");
}
```

In the other's page controller, define the service as a dependency and you will be able to access the up-to-date data.

Please note that I'm not a professional angularjs user or even a webdevelopper, you should probably wait for other users to react to my answer or add their own.

Comment: I'd like to, but the form is in a website that is not handled by me and that it should not be changed. This website redirect to mine when we submit the form.

Comment: @GuillaumeRahbari can you at least ask them to change the action URL? If so, setting $location to use html5mode in your angular app may help, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. And i tried the html5mode and it did not solve the problem :/

Comment: @GuillaumeRahbari Ok, so it is a given that the url will be at some point http://ncel28182/pl/Angular/?test=input#/FFCO, since that's what the external form explicitely sends. Now you need to intercept that request and redirect it where you want. First you need something to listen at http://ncel28182/pl/Angular/, which I guess your angularjs app already do. Then you need it to reroute to somewhere you want. I thought $location.html5Mode would do this by itself, but if it doesn't you can force it to.

Comment: If you already use ngRoute, I think you should create an "alias" to the route you would like to use, pointing the incoming url to the view you want. In other cases, just use $location to rewrite the url components as you want

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't edit the form sending data, you can't use ngRoute to directly route to the desired "FFCO" view because ngRoute matches against $location.path, whereas the form sends the "FFCO" part as the $location.hash. Since you have no $location.path provided, the form will target your application root.

What you will want to do is add some js code in this page to handle the location change :

```
if ($location.hash() === "/FFCO") { $location.path("/FFCO"); }
```

This should do the trick, translating the url requested by the form to a format understandable by your angularjs application. I don't think this will change the hash, if an extra #/FFCO by the end of your URL is a problem you should remove it with `$location.hash('')`.

I believe the best place to do so would be in an extra controller added somewhere after your app bootstrap code.

This is obviously still sub-optimal, I wish I had a better solution.